# HQL - COUNT on SELECT clause not working

Tags: java, mysql, hql, spring-data

I'm trying to create an HQL query that calculates several stats on a list on specific users for specific dates (for example, how many were logged in etc.). Each stat has a different criteria):

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(SELECT u2.id FROM User u2 WHERE u.id = u2.id AND u2.lastLoginDate BETWEEN x AND y), 
   COUNT(some other stats), ...
FROM User u 
WHERE u.managerId IN (...)
```

While the `COUNT(SELECT...)` clause worked in MySQL, in HQL I get the following exception: 
`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: SELECT`

Anyone know how to make it work?

EDIT: 
Ok, So according to this suggestion [HQL - COUNT on SELECT clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636084/hql-count-on-select-clause-not-working/27636725#27636725) now the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.lastLogin BETWEEN x AND y THEN u.id ELSE null END),
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ... END),
     SUM(CASE WHEN u.id = p.userId THEN p.amount ELSE null END),
FROM User u, Points p,...  WHERE u.managerId IN (...)
```

Problem is, the calculated SUM is not correct because of the From clause - it's multiplied by the number of tables.
For example if the total sum should be 80, and I have 4 tables in the from clause, the sum is instead 480!

Obliviously, distinct won't work correctly for sum. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an entirely different question.  In any case, simply follow a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Use explicit joins and you will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just want conditional aggregation.  It is unclear what you really want from the query, but this may be close:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u2.lastLoginDate BETWEEN x AND y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN some other stats THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), ...
FROM User u 
WHERE u.managerId IN (...)
```

I am surprised that `count(select . . . )` worked in MySQL.  First, subqueries usually require their own parentheses.  Second, in a `select`, a subquery generally needs to be a scalar subquery.  And third, subqueries are generally not allowed as arguments to aggregation functions.  Are you sure the construct wasn't `select count() . . .`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.
So, just a to clarify - there's no way to use count(select...) in HQL? Also, what if I need to use count distinct?

Comment: I'm not sure about HQL, but I doubt it.  The construct is not available in other dialects of SQL.  The simple solution is to do the aggregation *inside* the subquery, instead of making the subquery an argument to the aggregation function.

Comment: please see my new edit, I now have issues when I need to use SUM instead of COUNT

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SQL. 
Here is an example.

```
    String sql = "select {user.*} from User user";
    // here creates a hql query from sql
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity("user", User.class);
    List results = query.list();

    //Hibernate modifies the SQL and executes the following command against the database:

    select User.id as id0_, User.name as name2_0_ from User user
```

you can search for Native SQL.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Please see my edit, the problem is not '(' but count on select.
The solution you suggest won't work in my case.